# Include is not working to add files that exist

Tags: php, include

I am using Eclipse and Xampp to create a small web application called SwiftWiki.

For this, I am creating a config file that (currently) only contains a few lines that do not much other than set paths.
My path to this is: E:/xampp/htdocs/SwiftWiki/_include/config/config.php

But when I define the file as such:

```
<?php 
$title = isset($_REQUEST['pname']) ? $_REQUEST['pname'] : "Home";
define("ROOT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/");
define("CONFIG_PATH", ROOT . "_include/config/");
define("CLASS_PATH", ROOT . "_include/classes/");
```

And try this:

```
include CLASS_PATH . "base/wikimaster.php";
```

It returns a metric tonne of errors (I know this file exists via windows explorer)

*Errors*:

> Warning: include(E:/xampp/htdocs/SwiftWiki/_include/classes/base/wikimaster.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\SwiftWiki\_include\config\config.php on line 6
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'E:/xampp/htdocs/SwiftWiki/_include/classes/base/wikimaster.php' for inclusion (include_path='E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in E:\xampp\htdocs\SwiftWiki\_include\config\config.php on line 6

I do not understand that which is going wrong, I have done this before many times, I have got Apache and MySQL running, restarting localhost does nothing either...

Comment: Look at the file path in error. You are in Windows file system while using Linux path. Correct it and see if still getting error.

Comment: @NMoeini, what do you mean? I have done this a million times using Win path the same way...

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Look at `SwiftWiki_include` from the error and your `_include`  from the define statement

Comment: is the folder `SwiftWiki_include` only a typo or is it an actual folder name?

Comment: Mistake caused by the editor, there is a slash after SwiftWiki before _include, I will add this, thanks for bringing this to my attention

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Your `SwiftWiki` is still never in your define statement :) *hint hint*

Comment: Well... I'm an idiot... I think coffee is required!

Comment: Isn't this an issue with setting the absolute path to actually look in `htdocs` instead of `SwiftWiki`...?

Comment: Thank you @Rizier123, I think I need to sleep or have more coffee in me!

Comment: @webeno, yes, yes it was. I added `"/SwiftWiki/"` to the root define and it worked. Oopsies!

Comment: This is a good example of why relying on external config such as `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is a bad idea. Use self-contained paths based on `__DIR__`